# Is it possible to show totals last in Active Pivot Live?

Tags: activepivot

Feels like I'm asking something very obvious, but I can't seem to find a configuration for showing 'Grand Total' last (bottom or right) instead of first (top or left).

It is the first question asked by new Active Pivot Live users

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't have the grand total row/column at the bottom/right hand side of the pivot table like in excel. Someone has already asked for such a behavior but since it's a very rare demand, it is not in our short term roadmap. However, if you express an interest in having such a feature, it can be reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

ActivePivot Live only displays the result of your MDX query, as sent by the server. Thus, if you need to display grand totals on the bottom/right of your view, you can do it by modifying your MDX :

1. exclude the grand totals from your axis
2. add it with a union or braces at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
Hierarchize(Set_Expression , POST)
```

instead of

```
Hierarchize(Set_Expression)
```

in your Mdx query.

Comment: A little explanation as to why this would help solve the asked question would be useful.

Comment: The POST keyword has been supported for the Hierarchize function since ActivePivot 5.1. This puts the grand total at the end of the set.